# Using WEB API AudioEncoder to output opus frames

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, opus, web-mediarecorder, webcodecs

I am interested in using [Web API AudioEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioEncoder) to produce audio chunks compatible with some opus decoder e.g. [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus)

```js
const stream= await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:{}});
const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {rate: 16000});
rec.ondataavailable = e => {
  audioChunks.push(e.data);
  console.log(e.data)
}
```

This will usually give the data when I stop recording, alternatively, I can do

```js
var context = new AudioContext({sampleRate: 16000})
const mediaSource = context.createMediaSource(stream);
const bufferLength = 1280;
const node = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferLength, 2, 2);
node.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
  const data = e.inputBUffer.getChannelData(0);
  console.log(data);
}
source.connect(node);
node.connect(context.destination);
```

That is more appropriate to my application because it would give a chunk of data every time it reaches buffer length, in this case 2560 at 16kHz corresponds to 40ms.

How can I record the input in a [Audio encoding capable browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=audioencoder) and as I record produce opus frames that I can then decode using a standard opus decoder.

Comment: Even if your code doesn't "run", we need to see it, in the question itself. For instance, here I am on a phone, and I can't help you because jsfiddle isn't optimized for phones. And I'm not even using an assistive device or being blocked by a firewalll allowing only stackoverflow to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the pieces together

- Create an [AudioEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioEncoder/AudioEncoder), passing output and error handlers. And then configure it to use `{codec: 'opus'}`
- Use [MediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to get microphone data.
- construct an instance of [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext), passing your `{sampleRate, latencyHint: 'interactive'}`.  Latency hint `interactive` gives low latency and is the default option, other options are `balanced` and `playback` that will accept higher latency to get lower power consumption.
- You get the microphone data in the audio context by passing the microphone stream to `audioContext`.[createMediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)
- You dow-mix the audio by setting [channelCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/channelCount) from a [MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode) using `audioContext`.[createMediaStreamDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) to 1.
- Create a **non standard** [MediaStreamTrackProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrackProcessor) passing the first track of the destination node stream.
- Get the required [AudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioData) by piping
  the readable stream of the track processor to a new [WritableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream/WritableStream)

If you are interested here is a code snippet that (by the time I write this answer) will fail due to `DOMException: Invalid security origin`

```js
/**
 * Fill a dropdown with audio input options
 * @param {HTMLSelectElement} select 
 */
async function enumerateAudioDevices(select){
  while (select.firstChild) {
    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
  }
  for(const deviceInfo of await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()){
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || `microphone ${select.length + 1}`;
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Fill a dropdown with common sample rate options
 * @param {HTMLSelectElement} select 
 */
function fillCommonSampleRate(select){
  while (select.firstChild) {
    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
  }
  for(const [value, label] of [
    [16000, '16kHz'], 
    [24000, '24kHz'], 
    [32000, '32kHz'],
    [44100, '44.1kHz'], 
    [48000, '48kHz']
  ]){
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = value;
    option.text = label;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}

class CapturePipeline {
  constructor(sourceId, codec='opus', sampleRate=16000){
    this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    this.codec = codec;
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
    /**
     * @type {(AudioData) => any}
     */
    this.onrawdata = null;
    /**
     * @type {(EncodedAudioChunk, EncodingMetadata) => any}
     */
    this.onencoded = null;
  }
  async connect(){
    const mic = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.deviceId ? {
      audio: { exact: {deviceId: this.deviceId}}
    } : {audio: true})
    /**
     * @type {AudioContext}
     */
    this.audioContext = new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)({
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate,
      numberOfChannels: 1,
      latencyHint: 'interactive'
    })
    this.mic = await mic;
    /**
     * @type {MediaStreamAudioSourceNode}
     */
    this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.mic)
    /**
     * @type {MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode}
     */
    this.destination = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()
    this.destination.channelCount = 1;
    this.source.connect(this.destination)
    /**
     * @type {AudioEncoder}
     */
    this.encoder = new AudioEncoder({
      output: this.handleEncodedData.bind(this),
      error: this.handleEncodingError.bind(this)
    })

    this.encoder.configure({
      codec: this.codec,
      numberOfChannels: 1,
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate
    })
    /**
     * @type {MediaStreamTrackProcessor}
     */
    this.audioTrackProcessor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor({
      track: this.destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]
    })
    this.audioTrackProcessor.readable.pipeTo(new WritableStream({
      write: this.handleRawData.bind(this)
    }))
  }
  disconnect(){
    this.source.disconnect();
    delete this.audioTrackProcessor;
    delete this.encoder;
    delete this.destination;
    delete this.mic;
    delete this.source;
  }
  /**
   * {EncodedAudioChunk} chunk
   * {EncodingMetadata} metadata
   */
  handleEncodedData(chunk, metadata){
    if(this.onencoded){
      this.onencoded(chunk, metadata)
    }
    const data = new ArrayBuffer(chunk.byteLength)
    chunk.copyTo(data);
  }
  handleEncodingError(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

  /**
   * @param {AudioData} audioData 
   */
  handleRawData(audioData){
    if(this.onrawdata){
      this.onrawdata(audioData)
    }
    this.encoder.encode(audioData)
    audioData.close()
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener('load', setup)
function setup(){
  const audioSourceSelector = document.body.querySelector('select#audio-source')
  const audioCodecSelector = document.body.querySelector('select#audio-codec')
  const sampleFrequencySelector = document.body.querySelector('select#sample-frequency')
  const startRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('button#start-recording')
  const volumeBar = document.querySelector('div#volume-bar')
  const encodedLengthBar = document.body.querySelector('div#encoded-length')
  const rawLengthBar = document.body.querySelector('div#raw-length');
  /**
   * {CapturePipeline}
   */
  let pipeline = null;
  let rawLength = 0;
  let encodedLength = 0;
  let audioSampleArray = new Float32Array(0)
  setInterval(() => {
    if(rawLength > 0 && encodedLength > 0){
      const ref = Math.max(encodedLength, rawLength)
      encodedLengthBar.style.width = (90 * encodedLength / ref).toFixed(2) + '%';
      encodedLengthBar.textContent = (encodedLength / 1024).toFixed(1) + 'kB'
      rawLengthBar.style.width = (90 * rawLength / ref).toFixed(2) + '%';
      rawLengthBar.textContent = (rawLength / 1024).toFixed(1) + 'kB'
    }
  }, 250)

  enumerateAudioDevices(audioSourceSelector)
  fillCommonSampleRate(sampleFrequencySelector)
  for(const select of [
    audioSourceSelector, 
    audioCodecSelector, 
    sampleFrequencySelector]
  ) {
    select.addEventListener('change', e => {
      if(pipeline)pipeline.disconnect();
      pipeline = null;
    })
  }
  startRecordingBtn.addEventListener('click', async e => {
    pipeline = new CapturePipeline(
      audioSourceSelector.value,
      audioCodecSelector.value,
      +sampleFrequencySelector.value
    )
    pipeline.onrawdata = (audioData) => {
      rawLength += audioData.numberOfFrames * 2;
      if(audioData.numberOfFrames > audioSampleArray.length){
        audioSampleArray = new Float32Array(audioData.numberOfFrames)
      }
      audioData.copyTo(audioSampleArray, {planeIndex: 0});
      const rms = Math.sqrt(audioSampleArray
        .map(x => x*x)
        .reduce((a,b) => a+b) / audioSampleArray.length);
      volumeBar.style.width = (rms * 500) + 'px'
    }
    pipeline.onencoded = (chunk) => {
      encodedLength += chunk.byteLength
    }
    await pipeline.connect()
  })
}
```

```css
// Unnecessary, but if it looks better, why not?


#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.horizontal-heat {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, red);
}
div.mask {
  width:500px; height: 10px; overflow:hidden;
}

div.plot-bar {
  background-color:#40c4ff;
  border: 1px solid #404080;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <fieldset><legend>RECORD AUDIO</legend>
    <select id="audio-source"></select>
    <select id="sample-frequency"></select>
    <select id="audio-codec">
      <option value="opus" selected>Opus</option>
      <option value="vorbis">Vorbis</option>
      <option value="mp3">MP3</option>
      <option value="alaw">A-law PCM</option>
      <option value="ulaw">&mu;-law PCM</option>
      <option value="pcm">Linear PCM</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <button id="start-recording">start recording</button>
  <hr>

  Volume
  <div id='volume-bar' class="mask">
  <div class="horizontal-heat">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    Encoded length
    <div id="encoded-length" class="plot-bar"></div>
    s16 PCM Wave length
    <div id="raw-length" class="plot-bar" style="width: 90%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```